# AngularJS: Directive Inheritance: Controller and Scope

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, angularjs-directive

I've been looking up directive inheritance in AngularJS with little luck. I have an abstract directive (controller-only) which relies on certain parameters which would normally be in the directive scope. I can inherit the controller just fine, but it seems I must re-declare all the abstract directive's parameters on each derivation which means changes to the abstract directive's parameters must be manually included in each implementation.

Is there any way to inherit a directive's controller and scope/parameters?

---

Example only:

```
function Abstract($scope) {
    $scope.paramAbstractNeedsButDoesntExist

    // Do cool stuff
}

function Inheritor() {
    return {
        controller: ['$controller', function ($controller) {
            $controller('Abstract', {$scope: $scope});

            // Do my cool stuff
        }],
        ...
        scope: {
            // Inheritor's stuff
            paramInheritorNeeds: '@'
        }
    };
}
```

I've outlined what I'm doing. Feel free to suggest alternative approaches, but the main question still needs to be addressed.

Comment: abstract directive in the sense what?

Comment: Please provide code example of what it is you are trying to do. *"abstract directive"* doesn't mean anything without seeing what you are talking about

Comment: How are the parentheses qualifying that it's only a controller not explicit enough?

Comment: For the same reason a picture is worth a thousand words. Descriptions of having to re-declare variables without seeing code is pretty hard to follow without example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a service with a method that returns the abstract class' scope; the base class then extends that scope and adds it's own properties/parameters. I use `[$controller][1]` to inherit the abstract class' behavior. To that end I removed `bindToController` and `controllerAs` from the base class' directive definition; this way the abstract class can rely on its properties being on the scope parameter.